# Configuration (web.config) in REST Web Service

Tags: asp.net

I have created a REST web service in VS2010,c# in .NET4 which communicates with oracle database. I did not get any web.config created (by VS2010) with it. All my code and functionality works fine but I want have some configuration to with my web service eg Oracle username/ password, oracle sid etc How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe title of your question is wrong and it is related to web.config or your application/service configuration. Please edit your question to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your question relates more to how store connection string in web.config.

Here is some sample
http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/

[oracle database connection in web.config asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432576/oracle-database-connection-in-web-config-asp-net)