# Why do I get error "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, oracle10g

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" When try to connect visual studio 12 to oracle 10g[ [new2 new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opUjD.png)

Comment: can you give your connection string which you are use in your project for connect to oracle database.

Comment: Data Source=XE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=FER_EPINET;Password=fer_epinet;Unicode=True

Comment: service_name = XE in tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this connection string with some server and database params

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=urHost)(PORT=urPort)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=urOracleSID)));User Id=urUsername;
Password=urPassword;
```

chanage urHost,urPort,urOracleSID,urUsername,urPassword as per your database configuration.

if you are using web.config connection then you may use

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="{ConnectionName}" 
      connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" 
        providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

or if you using visual studio 2012 then follow below screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: this string has to be written in <connectionstring> tag in web.config??

Comment: yes @vikas you may write in your <connectionstring> tag in web.config and for reference you also use this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432576/oracle-database-connection-in-web-config-asp-net

Comment: is there any way by which i can establish a connection using UI

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="epinet" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=VikasShah)(PORT=1521)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));Persist Security Info=True;User ID=FER_EPINET;Password=fer_epinet;Unicode=True"
     providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: remove Persist Security Info=True; and Unicode=True attribute and first try from your vs2012 server explorer tab if this connection occured then not an issue.

Comment: i have tried server explorer tab also bt nothing works out

Comment: attach error screenshot while you are trying using server explorer tab.

Comment: as i am new to this website ..so its not allowing me to upload an image

Comment: uploaded the image

Comment: @vikas you are trying using vs oracle database connection provider but you may use odp.net for real time oracle dotnet provider for .net,you may try to installed from this url http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: please specify the size of the file

Comment: file size is 263 mb and url is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: i have the uploaded snapshot of the error page by name con 1 and con 2

Comment: @vikas i have changed my answers with attached screenshot.

Comment: i have installed the ODB.net from the link which u have sent .......but i cannot find th options which ur showing

Comment: i have uploaded the snapshot for the same

Comment: @vikas leave connection using server explorer tab try using connection string and run your program and let me know its run or not .

Comment: sir, i had tried using <connectionstring> bt after that nothing is displayed under server explorer tab.

Comment: data connections tab is empty

Comment: please sir provide any other way to connect coz i had used almost all the ways to connect bt nothing worked out